# Android onActivityResult called early

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have 2 Activities, each in seperate applications. Activity1 has a button the user can click and it calls the second activity using an intent in its `onClick()` method:

```
Intent myIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(com.myProject.Activity2);
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 600);
```

This correctly launches Activity2 from Activity1, but `onActivityResult` gets called in Activity1 before `onCreate` gets called in Activity2, instead of in `onBackPressed()` where I set up the return intent.

Here is the `onCreate` method for Activity2:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

Here is the current version of `onBackPressed` method for Activity2:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("Stuff", someStuff);

    if(getParent()==null){
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
    }else{
        getParent().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
    }
    finish();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

My AndroidManifest.xml has the following intent filter for Activity2:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
```

I verified that my `launchMode` is `standard` (and not `singleTask`, etc) as advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354955/onactivityresult-called-prematurely) and my request code is not negative as warned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289726/onactivityresult-not-being-called-when-listactivity-finishes). I also tried `android:launchMode="singleTop"`, but that was a no-go also.

I also tried not calling `finish()` in `onBackPressed()` for Activity2 as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742438/onactivityresult-not-called-in-android) (also with just `super.onBackPressed()` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322874/onactivityresult-has-intent-data-as-null-after-an-activity-has-finished)) and again calling it as suggested [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/b3b2ad819ee40eff#).

Additionally I tried commenting out the line `intent.putExtra("Stuff", someStuff);` as it seemed to cause trouble for [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019711/android-onactivityresult-not-called-triggered).

Any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So here is the final solution that took care of it:

I changed the intent for Activity1 to the following:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent();
myIntent.setClassName("com.myProject", "com.myProject.Activity2");
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 600);
```

For some reason Android requires the fully qualified name for the second parameter in addition to the package name given by the first parameter. Now it works! :)

Comment: Thank you very much for coming back and posting your solution. I have been stuck on this problem for a long time and I too tried all of the solutions you came across in your question to no avail. This fixed it and made my day a heck of a lot better =)

Comment: I use startActivityForResult WITHOUT setClassName or fully qualified names all over my projects and they all work perfectly except for one case.  So I tried your solution in that case and it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Sadly this haven't solved my issue, neither did the other answers!

Comment: This solved it for me too, in the specific case of communicating between two separate applications.

Answer (score 1):

It will happen if "singleInstance" flag is set when you launch the activity.

Comment: Thanks jbaylina your answer is helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

Not certain what your problem is. The way you're creating the Intent in Activity1 is odd; that method isn't meant for creating intents that launch another activity in the same app. Some developers use the Intent(Context, Class<>) constructor. I prefer to use Intent(String action) with a custom action string defined only in my app (which is easier to code correctly).

Also, the intent filter you've specified for Activity2 is usually used for an activity that's launched directly from the Home screen.

Where's the onCreate() code for activity2? Where's the code for onBackPressed()? Can you prove to me that setResult() is called before some other code in Activity2? You should run the activities in debug. Ensure that Activity2 is receiving the intent you think it should, then trace step by step the statements that are executed until setResult(). The thing *not* to do is throw solutions at the code before you understand what the underlying problem is.

As far as I can tell so far, Activity1 is sending out an Intent, and then onActivityResult is being called. Nothing else is proven so far.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - I've added the `onCreate` and `onBackPressed` methods to the question. I ran it debug many times and using break points I was able to show that Activity1's `onActivityResult` gets called when Activity2 first gets launched - before Activity2 ever returns, and does not get called again when it returns.

Comment: I also tried creating an intent using `Intent(context, Activity2.class)`, but it complained that it couldn't find the class (probably because it's in another application). I tried a few variations of using the fully qualified path name and that was a no-go also.