# get onActivityResult from externall app Andriod

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, onactivityresult, startactivityforresult

My App1 launch App2:

```
case R.id.launch_button: {
  try {
       Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.app1");
       intent.putExtra("Price", getAmount());
       intent.putExtra("Description", getProductId());
       startActivityForResult(intent, PAYMENT_REQUEST);
      } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i(TAG, "Activity not found" );
        }
        break;
    }
```

When App2 finish processing should return `RESULT_OK` or `RESULT_CANCELED`:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult " + requestCode + " " + resultCode + " " + data);
        if (requestCode == PAYMENT_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Payment success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Payment fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

but `RESULT_CANCELED` appears immediately when the App2 launch.
Why am I receiving `RESULT_CANCELED` before even the App2 launch? What I'm doing wrong?

App2 return result code:

```
@Override
public void onPaymentSuccess() {
    activity.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    activity.finish();
}
@Override
public void onPaymentFail() {
    activity.setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
    activity.finish();
}
```

I also dont receive any result when App2 finish..

**Note: App2 use Fragment**

Comment: You should call .setResult() on a new Intent. And call finish() as it is.

Comment: Why? It is not nessesary because I dont wonna pass any data to App1

Comment: problem solved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048813/android-onactivityresult-called-early/10075762 i use  intent.setClassName() instead getPackageManager